# Response times for successful requests only with blackbox exporter

Tags: metrics, prometheus, prometheus-blackbox-exporter

How can I measure the response times of successful requests only when using blackbox exporter?

As far as I understand the functionality even if the return code is not in the defined "valid range", the response is used for response time metrics.